# Where does the energy go in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, energy-conservation

The following is a fairly straightforward problem about momentum conservation in inelastic collisions (I am only interested in part (b) of the exercise). The question asks whether the kinetic energy of the system of wagon and persons changes due to the collision. The answer is that yes, the kinetic energy changes, because x-momentum is conserved. However, I am confused about where exactly the energy goes, or which force is doing work. It must be a static friction force, but does static friction dissipate energy?
[image: Problem description]

The solution goes as follows. Conservation of x-momentum yields
$$
Mv_{1x} = (M + m)v_{2x},
$$
where $M$ is the mass of the cart and $m$ is the combined mass of the two persons. Thus, the final kinetic energy is
\begin{align}
K_2 &= \frac{1}{2} (M + m) v_{2x}^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{M^2}{M + m}v_{1x}^2\\
&= \frac{M}{M + m} K_1,
\end{align}
where $K_1 = \frac{1}{2}Mv_{1x}^2$ is the initial kinetic energy.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/568455/inelastic-collision-and-kinetic-energy

Comment: @BobD I think this can be neglected because to slow them down a friction force (e.g. in their knees) only needs to act vertically, so it does no work in the x-direction. In the official solution they just assume they had a height of ≈0 so no potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy is not a conserved quantity. Only the momentum of an isolated system. In this example kinetic energy is lost due to the collision between the heroes and wagon being inelastic. Both the heroes and the wagon/gold "stick together" following the collision moving together with the same final velocity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don’t know why this is downvoted because KE is not conserved in an inelastic collision. 

The velocity changes, and is non-linearly related to KE = 1/2 mv^2.

Comment: @ErolBakkalbasi I didn't see a downvote

Comment: Thanks! I agree that kinetic energy is not conserved here. However, the change of kinetic energy is given by the work-energy theorem. Some force is doing work to slow down the wagon. If there is no kinetic friction involved, i.e. the heroes really just “stick” to the wagon, then what force is doing this work?

Comment: In the inelastic collision macroscopic KE  is converted to microscopic (internal) KE (increased molecular motion) in the inelastically colliding bodies . If you include the increase in internal KE, the work energy theorem still applies.

Comment: @OnnoEberhard according to Newton's 2nd law, it takes a force to accelerate the Lone Ranger and Tonto in a horizontal direction.  This force comes from the wagon, and that force is applied over a distance, meaning that the wagon did work on the two men.  Due to Newton's 3rd law, the men also did negative work on the wagon, slowing it down.  Work is equivalent to energy, so there is no "missing energy" in this problem.

Comment: @DavidWhite High David. If we consider the heroes + wagon as the system then isn’t all the work you refer to internal to the system?

Comment: @DavidWhite Thank you, I think this is the clearest explanation of what is going on. My mistake was assuming that this acceleration somehow happened instantaneously (over 0 distance), which would of course be unphysical.

Comment: @BobD, in my opinion, no.  The heroes dropped in from outside the system as I define it, which is the wagon loaded with gold.  And yes, I realize that there is more than one way to define the system.

Comment: True there is more than one way to define the system. If I choose to define the system as heroes + wagon and ignore work done by gravity (as appears to be the case) then wouldn’t you agree the net external work is zero? And what’s more, the total change in KE (macro +internal) is zero?

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the energy go in this problem ?

In an inelastic collision the "lost" kinetic energy is dissipated into the environment as sound and heat.